# Is my keyboard compatible with MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, high-sierra, mojave

I have ordered a Hyperx alloy elite RGB, but I was wondering whether it would be compatible with my MacBook Pro [Mojave 10.14.] In some forums I read it might not be compatible. If it is not compatible is there any possible way that I can make it work with my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Will all the letters & numbers work?
**Yes.**
You'll probably use the Windows key as Command, the others as labelled. Choosing a PC keyboard layout in System preferences may be helpful too.

Will all the media buttons & [customisation options](https://www.hyperxgaming.com/en/ngenuity) work?...

> Features
>
> Set up lighting and effects freestyle or by zone
> Create and store macros and button bindings
> Customise your keyboard’s Game Mode
> Library of game profile presets
> Adjust your mouse’s DPI settings
> Monitor battery life and adjust audio

**No.**
There are no Mac-specific drivers or custom control panel available.

Comment: thanks for clarification :). So does that mean i wouldnt be able to modify the RGB lighting ?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to modify anything, there's no control panel. The lighting may or may not work at all - you'll find out when you plug it in.